# Remove border circle from radio input

Tags: html, css

I wanted to use image instead of regular radio inputs.

[image]
[image]

I made it this way:

```
input[type="radio"]{
    content:url('/images/new-home-page/Checkbox.png');
    height:3vh;
    width:3vh;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked{
    content:url('/images/new-home-page/checkedCheckbox.png');
}
```

Unfortunately, they have circles around them. I have tried to use `border:none` or `text-decoration:none` but it doesnt help. Could someone help me with this please?

They look like this now:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `outline:none` ?

Comment: why is content ,not background? I've never used it before

Comment: Out of interested, why are you using a checkbox image with a radio button interface? Shouldn’t you be using `<input type="checkbox"/>`s so as not to confuse your user’s expectations of behaviour?

Comment: I'm using content because I found some stackoverflow users do it this way. The radio inputs are the right choice because my page users need to pick only one out of these two. It is a typical radio selection

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would request you to use the `appearance` property of CSS, which is responsible for the components like this. So setting the `appearance: none` will make a kind of `display: none` to the component's appearance, which is what is needed for you. You are good to use this bit of CSS to make the component not display, while keeping the element in the view:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
-ms-appearance: none;
-o-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```

**Snippet**

```css
input {
  content: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3EkO.png');
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
input:checked {
  content: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ialva.png');
}
```

```html
Checkbox:
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="" /> <br />
Radios:
<input type="radio" name="Hi" id="" />
<input type="radio" name="Hi" id="" />
```

**Output: http://output.jsbin.com/digebimolu/1**

Comment: @divHelper11 Have a look at the snippet I have added.

Comment: @divHelper11 The only downside this solution has, it won't work on IE 8,9,10,11. Check my answer if you need that.

Comment: @LGSon The OP's code `content: url()` doesn't work in IE 10 and below!!! Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132460/css-url-not-recognized-in-internet-explorer-10

Comment: @PraveenKumar I know, so I switched back to my original answer using `background` for the image, to support IE 8-11.

Answer (score 3):

You must hide radio buttons and add more elements like `<span>` and `<label>`

Here is how it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/etz9Lfat/

Comment: You must add code to your answer. Shouldn't just link to jsfiddle.

Comment: @PraveenKumar it needs only a small explanation, which you can see on the top

Comment: @PraveenKumar your answer has no explanation at all BTW :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a another interesting solution, using pseudo element, where you also get rid of the surrounding focus outline.

The really good with this is it works on IE 8-11 as well, which unfortunately the better solution using `appearence` don't.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}
input[type="radio"] + label {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 54px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size: 26px;
}
input[type="radio"] + label:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -22px;
    width:46px;
    height:46px;
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3EkO.png');
    background-size: contain;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ialva.png');
}
```

```html
<input id="cb" value="1" name="cb" type="radio">
<label for="cb">Text 1</label>
<input id="cb2" value="2" name="cb" type="radio">
<label for="cb2">Text 2</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest a whole other solution.

```css
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label{
    padding-left:35px;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:52px; /* width of the checkbox */
    height:53px; /* height of the checkbox */
    margin:-1px 10px 0 -35px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3EkO.png')  left top no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}

/* replaces the image if checked.*/
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
    background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ialva.png') left top no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<input id="cb" value="" type="checkbox">
<label for="cb"><span></span> Text</label>
```

With this Solution you wont have any Problems in all browsers.
It will hide the checkbox itself, but it still works because you can click the label, which is connected to the checkbox.
In this label there is a span with your background image and the sizes of it. So it still looks like a checkbox and your hidden checkbox will be "checked" or "unchecked"

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css file:

```
input[type=radio]{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Seriously? `display: none`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. `display:none` makes my checkboxes disapear. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @divHelper11 GLP is wrong. Don't worry. Getting you a correct solution.

Comment: @Praveen: What do you think about this then, If I'm wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528860/radio-button-styling.. For some problem, we can have multiple solutions, I showed my way of answer, If you have separately, well & good, For that dont tell blindly, my answer is wrong

Comment: @G.L.P Please use common sense. There is only one element, `<input />` and you are removing it out of the view. How on earth will it display then?

Comment: @G.L.P In the example you have given, there's another element `<input type="radio" id="radio"><label for="radio"></label>`, which is `label`. Can't you see that? Now do you say, will your solution help?

Comment: OP asked only for border, and there was no demo, I just shared my opinion.. like you do

Comment: I mean, it is evident from the CSS that there's only one single element, and do you still agree your answer doesn't work. Sorry if I am rude or something. `:(`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple work around to get customized radio buttons
https://jsfiddle.net/sudheer219/fj8heLcp/

Code:
[HTML]

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type='radio' value='1' name='radio' id='radio1'/>
        <label for='radio1'><span></span>Value 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type='radio' value='2' name='radio'  id='radio2'/>
        <label for='radio2'><span></span>Value 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type='radio' value='3' name='radio'  id='radio3'/>
        <label for='radio3'><span></span>Value 3</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

[CSS]

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

input {
  visibility: hidden;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked+label span {
  background: red;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px inset #444;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

Comment: This answer does not address the question as the radio input is still circle, while the question asks how to remove the circle